# pushState/onpopstate - go back multiple states

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

*Today I worked with the history API for the first time and ran into a problem:*
Sections 2, 3 and 4 got `display:none` and the first one `display:block`. When I click a link in my navigation, the current "page" fades out and the belonging section fades in.
To be able to navigate with the browsers "history buttons", the URL changes with `pushState` and I created that function:

```
var currentPage = $(".page:visible").attr('class').split(' ')[1];
var href = $(this).attr("href");

history.pushState(null, null, href + "/");

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    $(".page").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("." + currentPage).fadeIn();
    }, 200);
};
```

The variable `currentPage` gets the class name of the visible section, at the time the link got clicked. So to "go back" it just fades that class in.
Its pretty obvious that you can't go back multiple times with that method (and go forward). How can I get this to work, that I can go back multiple times and go forward aswell?
I prepared a little [codepen](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/ayOORB) with a full example. (Couldn't make a snippet because you need to go back, which isn't possible in a snippet)

Comment: Store the page reference (or number if that's what you want to use) as a fragment in the URL, eg `#1`, `#2` ... Then onpopstate you can read the fragment from the URL and show the appropriate page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The URL already changes to `pageOne`, `pageTwo`, ... at the end. So you mean I should extract the string from the URL and show the appropriate page?

Comment: Yep, that's it exactly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thaaanks alot!! Got it to work :)

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated my codepen, in case you wonder how I did it. The only problem now is, that the url is "emtpy" at the beginning (so there is no `pageOne`, `pageTwo`,...) and when I return to that site, nothing is fading in :/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You should write an official answer, so this question can be marked as solved.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus you need to run the code in the `setTimeout()` when the page loads too. That'll solve your problem there